# GPU problem/replacement ? For Lightroom and Vegas

Tags: video-editor, vegas-pro

I use both Sony Vegas Pro and Adobe Lightroom.
In my new computer is an Asus Strix GTX980 GPU card.

In Lightroom: I had to disable GPU acceleration
In Vegas: I have crashes as soon as the preview windows is resized of plays video. Even with GPU acceleration disabled. (Rendering works fine but I cannot work the video that way.

From what I read, there may be something wrong with applications support of Nvidia GTX9xx .
Maybe I can exchange the GPU for another.

Do you know if that GPU may be the problem ?
What GPU in the same price range would you recommend (with 3 screens in mind, 2x4K and 1xFullHD).
Should I go AMD?

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved for Vegas

**Solution A**

1. (optional) I have installed thedriver version I wanter (in my case I took the latest drivers,359.00 currently).
2. CTRL+Shift on Vegas icon, checked clear cache data. (Beware that you may lose some configuration in the process.)
3. After maybe a few starts (can't tell precisely), it finally works, WITH GPU acceleration.

**Solution B**
The problem happened again. Solution this time. It might look like a random thing but I've done it multiple times and tested alternatives.

(There was no driver update this time.)

1. Start Vegas with a blank projet.
2. Display Preview Window (content should be all black).
3. Resize preview window (not sure if this is optional, but if it doesn't crash at this point, that's a good sign).
4. Open the project you initially intended to work with.

Regarding Lightroom: no solution yet.